# Web Statistics Software or Analytics?

Tags: awstats, analytics

Do you use web statistics software like Awstats,  Weblizer etc... (any other popular ones?)

Or do you prefer to use Google Analytics and embed the JavaScript in each page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For my personal site, I tend to use both awstats and Google analytics. Awstats is more accurate, but Google provides information awstats just can't. One disadvantage of Google is including javascript, which could affect your page load time.

No one should use webalizer because it's just so damned ugly :)

Comment: +1 for Google Analytics.  I've used it on MANY sites and love it.  Never had a problem with the JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) over self-hosted solutions. Depending on the number of hits your sites get, you'll have to run a dedicated machine for your web analytic software. Also, there is less administrative overhead (copying log files, handling user accounts etc.) if you outsource the service.

Google Analytics provides some "Enterprise" features, which a difficult to find in other *free* solutions:

- scalable for any size
- analyzing subsets of the traffic
- custom reports
- motion charts
- track and compare campaigns
- benchmarking
- trends
- funnel visualization
- geo targetting

Answer (score 1):

I think it all depends on what you're looking to get out of your stats.

If you're looking for as it happens traffic data, Awstats is the way to go.

If you're looking for custom reporting, trending data, ad tracking, not to mention pretty graphs and a good UI, go with Google Analytics.

However since they're both free, I say don't limit yourself and use both as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

I run the log files through [visitors](http://www.hping.org/visitors/); which I think is quite nice. Using [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) it can produce graphs visualizing the path people take through a website.

Answer (score 0):

We use Webtrends for our analysis. Have used it and also seen some huge corporate using it.
Along with Webtrends have also used AWSTATS.

Answer (score 0):

I never considered self-hosted web tracking solution because simply I don't want to add one more thing in my list to manage.

I use both google analytics and [Reinvigorate](http://www.reinvigorate.net/) the same time on my sites. Both work great. Never had any problem with them. I usually check Google Analytics end of the day and the other during the day, as Reinvigorate provides information more in real time while Google Analytics delays most of the time.