# Website analytics software

Tags: analytics

Greetings,

I know about google etc. However I'd like some analytics software which I can run against my own server logs. Can anyone suggest a package I could use? Ideally free :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two big players (on the linux side at least):

- [awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/)
- [webalizer](http://www.mrunix.net/webalizer/)

Though awstats is considered to be "prettier"!

Comment: One vote behind awstats it's pretty easy to configure and works on both Windows and Linux  (provided you have access to Perl)

Comment: Both are great solutions. +1

Answer (score 0):

I'm stupid.

I checked out 
[Web Statistics Software or Analytics?](https://serverfault.com/questions/21055/web-statistics-software-or-analytics)

But I'm open to other suggestions.